# \raggedright in wrapfigure environments

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

A small width in wrapfigure sometimes gives captions with ugly spacings because of the standard right/left justification.  How can I get \raggedright to work in the caption?
I've received the desired result by placing \raggedright inside the caption EXCEPT for the fact that the typesetting stops prematurely. Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{.3\textwidth}
\caption{\raggedright The wordlengths in this caption are the problem.}
\vskip20pt
(figure)
\vskip20pt
\end{wrapfigure}
Now is the time for all good men to  come to the aid of their country.
Now is the time for all good men to  come to the aid of their country.
Now is the time for all good men to  come to the aid of their country.
Now is the time for all good men to  come to the aid of their country.
Now is the time for all good men to  come to the aid of their country.
Now is the time for all good men to  come to the aid of their country.
Now is the time for all good men to  come to the aid of their country.
Now is the time for all good men to  come to the aid of their country.
Now is the time for all good men to  come to the aid of their country.
Now is the time for all good men to  come to the aid of their country.
Now is the time for all good men to  come to the aid of their country.
Now is the time for all good men to  come to the aid of their country.
\end{document}
```

In this case after hitting RETURN four times in response to questions and some code that I do not recognize, the resulting document appears with the desired raggedright caption.  How can I get this end result without these extra RETURNs keyed to the console?

Comment: Welcome To TeX.SE! Please provide a small but complete document (MWE: Minimal Working Example), which show what you doing.

Comment: Any news? Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 3):

Your MWE works fine, so it is not clear, what is your problem For sure it is not caused with word "wordlength".

[image]

To my opinion above result is not very pleasant. I would do the following changes in your MWE:

- Use `caption` package for defining captions style,
- Never define caption style in caption text. Do this in document preamble, or with `\captionsetup` before caption.
- With help of `etoolbox` package you can define caption style for selected environment(s). For example in your case

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}           % for environment hooks
\AtBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{% for caption style in wrapfigure
        \captionsetup{font=small,
                      justification=RaggedRight}
                                }
```

- With `\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}` the surplus vertical space before and after `wrapfigure` is removed. It can be added to preamble on the similar way as caption style:

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{% remove vertical space around wrapfigue
        \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}
```

- For caption in narrow environments, as are `wrapfigure`, smart hyphenation of longer words enable better caption text formatting
- If default hyphenation  patterns not contain suggestion for some long word, is sensible add list of this words in preamble. For example in your case

```
\hyphenation{word-lengths}
```

- Better words spacing in text (as well in captions) can be achieved by employment of `microtype` package

With considering aforementioned suggestions, yor MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\hyphenation{word-lengths}      % here collect long words which not hyphenate

\usepackage{wrapfig}
% added packages needed in this MWE
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}           % used in definition od caption style (at least) in wrapfigure
\usepackage{caption}            % for defining caption style
\usepackage{etoolbox}           % for environment hooks
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{% remove vertical space around wrapfigue
        \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{% for caption style in wrapfigure
        \captionsetup{font=small,
                      justification=RaggedRight}
                                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
        \caption{The wordlengths in this caption are the problem.}
        \label{fig:a}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[44]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this result acceptable to you?